# Upgrading from Ruby 1.9.2p290 to 1.9.3p2 without using rvm on linux server

Tags: ruby, linux

I am having ruby-1.9.2p290 and rails 3.0 installed on my machine. 
When i am trying to install rails 4.0 as

```
[root@TKDEVSERVER ~]# gem install rails -v '4.0'
Fetching: i18n-0.6.11.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.10.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: minitest-4.7.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: activesupport-4.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

and when i try to install ruby:

```
[root@TKDEVSERVER ~]# sudo apt-get install ruby-1.9.3p2
sudo: apt-get: command not found
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Please help me out. How to upgrade without using rvm?

Comment: What version of linux are you using? Type `lsb_release -irc` at the command line and provide the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` is a package manager for Debian-based distributions, e.g. Ubuntu, Debian. Other distributions have different package managers. My first guess would be that it's `yum`, but depending on which OS you use it may be not the case.